# get location +20px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

     //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
     $('a[name=popup]').click(function(e) {
      //Cancel the link behavior
      e.preventDefault();

      //Get the A tag
      var id = $(this).attr('href');

  //Set the popup window to center
  $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
  $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
```

can i change the popup window below the a href tag(top:dom?+20px) and not center??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `top` to this:

```
$(id).css('top', $(this).offset().top + 20);
```

[`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns the position of the clicked link, and you want the `top` value, this returns the top of the clicked link, so you may want to add it's height as well, e.g.:

```
$(id).css('top', $(this).height() + $(this).offset().top + 20);
```

Comment: i mean get the a href tag current location and +20

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a[name=popup]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        //e.preventDefault(); //return false handles this

        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        var position = $(this).position();

        //Set the top value to be 20px from the top
        $(id).css('top', (position.top + 20) + 'px');

        return false;
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/position/